# What are these Black textures on my donut?

Tags: objects

So I was working on a Donut (following a Tutorial on YouTube)and Theres keep coming thus weird black texture on it. I have re-made the donut too and it still appears…I‘d be thankful for help or any advices!

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe the faces of the object underneath that are overlapping?

Comment: A I’m sorry I don’t really know what you mean by that may I ask what I should do?

Comment: what happens if you select the donut, go in Edit mode, move its top faces down?

Comment: I separated them and then it’s gone but once they come together it’s back

Comment: OH OH it’s gone idk how but it left aa sorry for wasting your time, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

:D this effect that @moonboots introduced you to in a way is called "Z-fighting". It's and artefact caused by imperfection of the calculations done by the 3d engine - 3d engine as its "common" issue between different 3d engines. As your screen is in the end a flat 2d canvas, there are series of functions that will translate virtual 3d objects onto that canvas in a way that it will try it best to represent depth and perspective. But, as there are sin and number Pi involved, and to be efficient 3d engines cant use to many decimal numbers, some approximation do occur.
When there are 2 virtual 3d surfaces overlapping, due to the approximations, render engine is not sure which pixel of each surface is in front and which one is in back - hence the weird artifacts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Comment: Oh oh I found a solution thank you for the explanation